# Why I have java.io.NotSerializableException in kotlin android app?

Tags: kotlin, serialization

I have a class which I'm trying to send to another activity using `putExtra`. The problem is I'm getting  `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.trachtenbergsystem.level.generator.GeneratorMultiply`.

This is GeneratorMultiply:

```
@Serializable
class GeneratorMultiply(private val difficulty: Double, private val exampleType: ExampleType, private val multiplier : Int = 0) : Generator() {
    private val base : Double = 1.4

    override fun gen(): Example {
        var num = ""
        var isLeft : Boolean
        var digit : String
        var center : Int
        var rand: Int

        for (i in 0 until difficulty.toInt()) {
            // Determine from which side digits are chosen
            // If it's 6, we can choose 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 on the left side, or 7, 8, 9 one the right one.
            center = (difficulty * 10).toInt() % 10

            if (center == 0) isLeft = false
            else if (center == 9) isLeft = true
            else isLeft = arrayOf(false, true).random()

            if (isLeft) {
                rand = (base.pow(10 - center).toInt() until base.pow(10).toInt()).random()
                digit = (log(rand.toDouble(), base).toInt() - (9 - center)).toString()
            } else {
                rand = (base.pow(center).toInt() until base.pow(10).toInt()).random()
                digit = (9 - log(rand.toDouble(), base).toInt() + center).toString()
            }

            num += digit
        }

        return Example("$num * $multiplier", (num.toInt() * multiplier).toDouble())
    }

}
```

I also maked `Serializable` All my objects which are inside this classes.

Example:

```
@Serializable
data class Example (var problem: String, var solution: Double) : java.io.Serializable
```

ExampleType:

```
@Serializable
enum class ExampleType : java.io.Serializable {
    MULTIPLYND1D,
    MULTIPLY2D2D,
    MULTIPLYND2D,
    MULTIPLYND3D,
    MULTIPLYNDND
}
```

And Generator, which is parent of GeneratorMultiply:

```
@Serializable
open class Generator {

    open fun gen(): Example {
        return Example("1 * 1", 1.0)
    }

}
```

I can't find where is thing which breaks serialization(.

Comment: Why do you want to send it to another activity? IMO, it's better to pass the attribute instease.